# In Debug Mode, API Request works. Release Mode, returns null

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I am near complete with my react-native app using the iOS simulator to test it. In the Debug Mode, the api requests successfully work and display on the app. However, in Release Mode, only the login request works.

My current details are the following:

```
 react-native: 0.60.3,
 native-base: 2.13.5,
 react-native-cli: 2.0.1,

 Visual Studio Code 1.36.1 
 Xcode 11 beta 7
```

I've done the following:

- Added domains to Permissions in info.plist
- Used different API servers to see if the server I was using was causing the problem
- Tried different optimizations with Debug and Release Mode in Xcode

This login API Request works and returns the token I want:

```
async(data) => {
            try{
                const url = 'https://assets.breatheco.de/apis/credentials/auth'
                let response1 = await fetch(url, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify(data),
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization':'application/json',
                        'Content-Type':'application/json'
                    }, 
                });
                // console.log(response)
                let res = await response1.json();
                if (response1.status >= 200 && response1.status < 300) {
                    data.error = "";
                    let user = res;
                    console.log('userToken: ', user, typeof(user))
                    getActions().userToken.store(user);
                } else {
                    let error = res;
                    console.log("something went wrong in getting userToken", error, getStore().userToken);
                    return false;
                    throw error;
                }

            } catch(error) {
                {() => getActions().userToken.remove()};
                console.log("Email: ", data.username);
                console.log("Password: ", data.password);
                console.log("Error: ", error);
                throw data.error;
            }
        }
```

And this is how my project receives its assignments.

```
async() => {
       console.log('entering get Tasktoken')
            try {
                let store = getStore()
                let session = store.userToken;

                let accessToken = session.access_token;
                let student_id = session.id;
                console.log(student_id)

                const taskURL = "https://api.breatheco.de/student/" + student_id + "/task/" 
                console.log('link is '+ taskURL);

                let response2 = await fetch(taskURL, { 
                    method: 'GET',
                    cache: 'no-cache',
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'},
                    body: JSON.stringify(),

                    });
                let tasks = await response2.json();
                console.log('tasks:',tasks)
                getActions().taskToken.store(tasks);

            } catch(error) {
                console.log('something went wrong in getting taskToken', error)
            }
```

It comes down to receiving the projects and assignments.

In debug mode, I get the desired output of arrays and expect the same in release mode:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8mTq.jpg

But instead, the output I receive is returned as null and in release mode is this:

```
Error: { [Error: No input to stringify] }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov7Sk.jpg

Comment: is there any api secret keys for debug and release ? may both keys are different for both enviroments and you are using debug key in release too ? .

Comment: @AbuUlHassan It seems the issue was the iOS version I was using (iOS 12.0 and below).  The problem with the release mode disappears when I switch to iOS 13.0.  So now I'm going to install previous versions of XCode to make it compatible with 10.0 and above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This is my step by step journey with this issue.

1. **Factory Reset**

   - I ended up having to do a factory reset
   - Also had to upgrade again to the latest Catalina/Xcode.
2. **Started Project Fresh**

   - I saved the src file, package.json, the app icons, and other specifics
   - Built it with a new project with `react-native init AwesomeNativeBase`
3. **Changed Deployment Target**

   - I searched all `IOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = {version number here}` in the file program and changed it to 11.0.
   - Kicked it off with a `pod install`
4. **Update React and React-Native**

   - Its FUNDAMENTAL you have the latest version of React and React-Native.
   - Make sure to check their websites

---

Its not the cleanest solution but its what worked for me.

Comment: This is very expensive process when you have larger project